# button click event take priority over row click event

Tags: jquery, html

I have two conflicting events that I want to get working.

I have a HTML table. The first column in the table is a button. this will open n details window.

I use these click events.

This one is to allow multi line select if you want to delete records.

> ```
>     $( "#vidlib_dtable tbody" ).on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
>         $(this).toggleClass('selected');
>     });
> ```

and This event is to pick up the button click to enable you to edit the record (open edit window)

> ```
>      $('#vidlib_dtable input[type="button"]').click(function() {
>           var dtab = $('#vidlib_dtable').dataTable();
>           var position = dtab.fnGetPosition(this); 
>           var contactId = dtab.fnGetData(position)[9];
>      });
> ```

How can I get the button click to take priority over the row click?

**EDIT**
The click event of the button still does not fire. Possibly a different way to call the event? Here is a example of the cell that holds the button in the HTML table

```
<td class="sorting_1 MMcol1">
    <div class="col1d">
        <button class="editBut"><img src="img/spanner.png"></button>
    </div>
</td>
```

**SOLUTION**

```
$( "#vidlib_dtable" ).on( 'click', 'tr', function () {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
});

$('#vidlib_dtable').on('click','.editBut',function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation(); /*   <-----  Put this before other steps   */
    var dtab = $('#vidlib_dtable').dataTable();
    var position = dtab.fnGetPosition(this);
    var contactId = dtab.fnGetData(position)[9];
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to stop event propagation on child elements event. use:

```
 e.stopPropagation();
```

Click event:

```
 $('#vidlib_dtable').on('click','.editBut',function(e) {
      var dtab = $('#vidlib_dtable').dataTable();
      var position = dtab.fnGetPosition(this); 
      var contactId = dtab.fnGetData(position)[9];
      e.stopPropagation();
 });
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/79tg5/)**

Comment: Okay I trust that the answer should be this, because there is 3 identical ones, but the click event of the button still does not work. I will append a example of the table in the code above. thanks so faf

Comment: I believe you must be appending the buttons dynamically too(as you have used event delegation for row click). you need to handle the click events for button in same way. i.e. using event delegation to bind click. See the updated code.

Comment: .Thanks. If you have a look at the table cell snippet above. Ive tried `$('#vidlib_dtable').on('click','input[type="button"]',function(e) {` but it still ignored the button event and went for the row event.

Comment: @mornenel: try the updated snippet. You have used wrong button selector.

Comment: Im afraid not. same result

Comment: do all the buttons have class `editBut`. also try using `$('#vidlib_dtable').on('click','button',function(e) {`. also put the alert inside button click event handler. and see how it goes.

Comment: Yes they all belong to that class, nope using button also did not work. Does the physical order in which the code appear matter? Like row click is before button click in the code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57906/discussion-between-milind-anantwar-and-morne-nel).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [stopPropagation](http://api.jquery.com/event.stoppropagation/):

```
$('#vidlib_dtable input[type="button"]').click(function(e) {
          var dtab = $('#vidlib_dtable').dataTable();
          var position = dtab.fnGetPosition(this); 
          var contactId = dtab.fnGetData(position)[9];
          e.stopPropagation();
     });
```

Answer (score 2):

If your button over row - you can use

```
$('#vidlib_dtable input[type="button"]').click(function(e) {
          var dtab = $('#vidlib_dtable').dataTable();
          var position = dtab.fnGetPosition(this); 
          var contactId = dtab.fnGetData(position)[9];
          e.stopPropagation();
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

Small correction to make it work on IE also

use below:

```
$('#vidlib_dtable input[type="button"]').click(function(e) {
      var dtab = $('#vidlib_dtable').dataTable();
      var position = dtab.fnGetPosition(this); 
      var contactId = dtab.fnGetData(position)[9];
      e = e||event;/* get IE event ( not passed ) */
      e.stopPropagation? e.stopPropagation() : e.cancelBubble = true;
 });
```